# jasmine-node waitsFor() stops all future runs()

Tags: node.js, jasmine, jasmine-node

The first runs creates a user, and the second runs gets the user from the server. The WaitsFor is supposed to cause the second runs to wait until the first runs is done. However, when running node-jasmine, the test stops after `before: 51c21c1ef463390000000008` is printed, without making the get request.

I've tried taking out the waitsFor, but that causes the get request to happen prior to the post request, which causes it to fail because it depends on a new user's `userid`.

What's going on?

```
var request = require('request');

describe("User", function(){
  var userid;
  it ("creates user", function(){

    runs(function(){
      var username = 'test' + Math.floor((Math.random()*100000)+1);

      var body = {
        username: username,
        email: username + "@test.com",
        password: username + "@test.com"
      };

      var options = {
        uri: 'http://localhost:3000/api/user',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(body)
      };


      request(options, function(err, res, body) {
        expect(res.statusCode).toEqual(200);
        console.log(body);
        var newUser = JSON.parse(body)[0];
        userid = newUser._id;
        console.log("before: "+ userid);

        expect(newUser.toBeTruthy());
      });
    });

    waitsFor(function() {
      console.log(typeof userid != "undefined");
      return (typeof userid != "undefined");
    }, "userid is never set", 10000);

    //it ("gets user", function() {
    runs(function(){
      expect(userid).toBeFalsy();
      console.log("this: "+userid);
      request.get("http://localhost:3000/api/user/" + userid, function(err, res, body){
        console.log("statuscode:" + res.statusCode);
        expect(res.statusCode).toEqual(2000);
        expect(body).toBeTruthy();
        console.log('Response: ' + body);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to use the `done()` function you can pass into `beforeEach`, I've tried to apply this to your example here below;

```
var request = require('request');

describe("User", function() {
  var getBody;
  var getRes;
  var newUser;
  var postBody;
  var postRes;
  var userId;

  beforeEach(function(done) {
    var username = 'test' + Math.floor((Math.random() * 100000) + 1);

    request({
      uri: 'http://localhost:3000/api/user',
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        username: username,
        email: username + "@test.com",
        password: username + "@test.com"
      })
    }, function(err, _postRes, _postBody) {
      postRes = _postRes;
      postBody = _postBody;
      newUser = JSON.parse(postBody)[0];
      userId = newUser._id;

      request.get("http://localhost:3000/api/user/" + userId, function(err, _getRes, _getBody) {
        getRes = _getRes;
        getBody = _getBody;
        done();
      });
    });
  });

  it("creates user", function() {
    expect(postRes.statusCode).toEqual(200);
    expect(newUser.toBeTruthy());
    expect(getRes.statusCode).toEqual(2000);
    expect(getBody).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```